# How to flood fill a color in texture paint?

Tags: workflow, texture-painting

In texture paint mode how do I fill a single colour (solid or transparent) on existing paints? 
I currently paint with large brush filling complete area. Is there any faster method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [recently added *Fill* brush](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Painting#Fill_Tool):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Fill threshold should be 1 i believe to flood entire paint area. gandalf3 what is the use of threshold less than 1 ?

Comment: @ashwin To fill areas of similar color, e.g. http://www.pasteall.org/pic/87623

Comment: does this work even with texture flood fill ?

Comment: @ashwin If you want to fill the entire area, you may want to use a Threshold value larger than 1 (say, 2 for example. And, since 1 is the default limit, you have to manually type it in there)

Answer (score 3):

Another way (if acceptable) is to use **Anchored** stroke method. Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: does this work even with texture flood fill ?

Comment: I think it can fill anything, yes?